# How do you get pixel information from an Image object in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, image, pixel

I have an Image object from the Windows Image Class and I want to get information on specific pixels.

Like, for example, if I have:

```
Image* myImage = Image::FromFile(L"example.jpg");
```

I would like to call something like:

```
myImage->GetPixel(400,400).red;
```

that should tell me the value of red for the pixel at coordinates 400x400.

But there is no such method, or at least I'm unable to find it. There's only a method for getting the pixel format, which doesn't help me.

How can I go about getting information on specific pixels?

More info on the class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534462(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This class abstracts such detail away from you. i.e. there are no pixels, just an image. Why do you think you need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the file or stream to create a Bitmap object instead:

```
Bitmap *myBitmap = new Bitmap("example.jpg");
Color pixelColor;
myBitmap->GetPixel(400, 400, &pixelColor);
cout<<(int)pixelColor.GetRed()<<endl;
```